# HttpClient post via Url not working in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, http-post, httpclient

I am trying to make a http post via uri using HttpClient like below.

```
var request = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  request.Add("FirstName", "Sibi");

  var requestData= new FormUrlEncodedContent(request);

  var httpClient= new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential
                    {
                        UserName = settings.Username,
                        Password = settings.Password
                    },
                    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
                });

  // Set the base address
  httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.Url);  

  var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri)
                {
                    Content = requestData
                };

    var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(req);
```

But somehow to the target url request is going via Body. I checked in fiddler and it looks like below

```
POST http://localhost:65518/api/Employee/Create HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 45
Host: localhost:65518

FirstName=Sibi&LastName=P.G&Age=23&Salary=100
```

I don't have any clue why it is not going via Uri. Any help will be really appreciated. I am trying to hit a local url(running in IIS express with VS 2015). I am in .net core 1.0.1

Comment: The code is sending the content in the body of the request. If you want it in the URL you need to construct the URL with the desired parameters.

Comment: I believe FormUrlEncodedContent is to take care of sending the content via Uri https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/how-to-call-httpclient-postasync-with-a-query-string/

Comment: The Fiddler is accurate because content is sent in the body of the request.

Comment: Looks like I found something. There was a [FromUri] attribute and I just removed. Now I am able to receive values. [Route("Create")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Employee employee)
        {
            return Ok(employee);
        }. But data is still getting transported via Body. Looks like HttpClient will only transport via Body. However I can hit via appending UriEncoded parameters to target Uri from Fiddler.